# How do I get Indev 0.31 in the Minecraft launcher without fiddler or anythings needed to download (except the thingy)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

I have tried everything on the internet and nothing works. Can someone tell me how to get it in launcher version 1.6.70?

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** [Even if you installed Indev 0.31, you wouldn't be able to play it correctly.](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Indev#Trivia)

Looks like [MCVersions.net](https://mcversions.net) doesn't have Indev 0.31, but you can also use these versions instead:

- [inf-20100618, after indev 0.31](https://launcher.mojang.com/mc/game/inf-20100618/client/89eab2c1a353707cc00f074dffba9cb7a4f5e304/client.jar)
- [c0.30_01c, before indev 0.31](https://launcher.mojang.com/mc/game/c0.30_01c/client/54622801f5ef1bcc1549a842c5b04cb5d5583005/client.jar)

Comment: look for another website maybe and tell me if you find a website with 0.31 and ill download it.